# Spring MVC bind hibernate session factory other thread in spring web mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

How to bind a hibernate session to a thread likes (QuartzSchude). As i have the instance of sessionFactory from application context. I want bind this to email thread, webservie thread and et...With http req and response it working fine..

Answer (score 0):

You need to either go through AOP decorated transactional bean (e.g. your service layer annotated with `@Transactional`), or you need to use `TransactionTemplate`:

```
new TransactionTemplate(txManager).execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
        // Your Hibenrate stuff
        return null;
    }
});
```